# laravel 5.5 I can not upload my project to the server

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload my project to a shared server but I can not, the steps I have followed have been the following:

1- I created a folder outside of public_html and I called it mascotas, there I stored all the folders except the public folder

being as follows:
[image]

2.-inside public_html I have saved everything inside the public folder

[image]

3.- I have changed the routes within the index file so that they point to the vendor folder, however the error continues, what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your image links do not work. They are deed.

Comment: What error? I'm not sure how you expect anyone to help when you haven't even told us what the error is.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: it's a http error 500

Comment: What does it say in the error log?

Comment: it says " the page can not process this request now".

Comment: i suggest checking if it's possible to set your server root under mascotas/public

Comment: Could this be the reason why composer is not installed in the hosting?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it, all was caused by the version of php